# Going from IQueryable<String> to String

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, model

I have a Model, which is below:

```
[Table("WebsiteText")]
public class WebsiteTextModel
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string WebsiteSection { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string TextToDisplay { get; set; }
}
```

I have a DataContext class, which is below:

```
public class WebsiteTextContext : DbContext
{
    public WebsiteTextContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<WebsiteTextModel> WebsiteText { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use LINQ to get the website text for my homepage, and stuff it into the ViewBag, so I am trying this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var context = new WebsiteTextContext();

    var result = from x in context.WebsiteText
                 where x.WebsiteSection == "Home Page"
                 select x.TextToDisplay;

    ViewBag.Message = result;

    return View();
}
```

However var is IQueryable, and I can't figure out how to get it to string. This doesn't work:

```
string result = from x in context.WebsiteText
    where x.WebsiteSection == "Home Page"
    select x.TextToDisplay;
```

This doesn't work:

```
var result = from x in context.WebsiteText
    where x.WebsiteSection == "Home Page"
    select x.TextToDisplay.ToString; //It's still IQueryable<String>
```

And this doesn't work:

```
var result = from x in context.WebsiteText
    where x.WebsiteSection == "Home Page"
    select x.TextToDisplay.ToArray; //It's now IQueryable<char[]>
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: So do you want the first string, do you want to join the strings, do you want an `IEnumerable<string>`, a collection of strings, the last string, the string with the longest text, what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string result = (from x in context.WebsiteText
where x.WebsiteSection == "Home Page"
select x.TextToDisplay).FirstOrDefault();
```

You also have `First` and `Single` and `SingleOrDefault`

Look them all up and pick which version works best for you.

Comment: This is the answer. The problem was that iQueryable is deferred execution and needs to be executed using one of the methods listed here.

Comment: What makes you assume he wants the first string, as opposed to say the last, or all of them, or a collection, etc.?

Comment: I guess `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` fit the situation best. | @Servy Eli posted several alternatives.